# How much damage can a rogue PHP developer do?

Tags: php, security

It's often convenient to hire a remote contractor for front-end development. Frameworks, like Laravel, use [PHP to render front-end](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) so it would make sense to give the front-end developer rights to edit PHP views files that render the HTML.

I can think of two possible security risks:

1. Can the developer use PHP to copy the entire database?
2. Can the developer use PHP to traverse up the directory tree and access the entire back-end source code.

If any of the above are possible, is there anything I can do to mitigate these risks? Minor risks are acceptable, but I'm concerned about the scenario when the developer copies the entire source code or database or both.

Comment: A lot less than a rogue C developer.

Answer (score 9):

Giving a malicious developer access to any portion of your infrastructure is extremely risky. They could write code from many different points that either give them back doors to your services or, possibly worse, your users.

Simply put, if you're even a little worried that someone might be a security threat, just find someone else. If that means paying more for someone local, do that. Even competent, trustworthy devs make headline-grabbing, company-sinking errors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if a dev has access to the db, they can copy it or delete it. If they have access to the source code, they can copy or delete it.

To mitigate this make backups, and use source control. But those are not really meaningful. Technology can’t fix people problems.

For this sort of thing, you need to manage the person. Hire well, keep people happy, and have a lawyer handy in case they cross the line.

Comment: Log. Lawyer is much more of a deterrent if you log.